# Auto-encoder for vector encodings

Tags: pytorch, autoencoder

Here is an autoencoder I wrote to encode two vectors :

`[1,2,3]` & `[1,2,3]`

The vectors are created in : `features = torch.tensor(np.array([ [1,2,3],[1,2,3] ]))`

This works as per code :

```
%reset -f

epochs = 1000
from pylab import plt
plt.style.use('seaborn')
import torch.utils.data as data_utils
import torch
import torchvision
import torch.nn as nn
from torch.autograd import Variable

cuda = torch.cuda.is_available()
FloatTensor = torch.cuda.FloatTensor if cuda else torch.FloatTensor
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt


features = torch.tensor(np.array([ [1,2,3],[1,2,3] ]))

print(features)

batch = 2
data_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(features, batch_size=2, shuffle=True)

encoder = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(3,batch), nn.Sigmoid())
decoder = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(batch,3), nn.Sigmoid())
autoencoder = nn.Sequential(encoder, decoder)

optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(params=autoencoder.parameters(), lr=0.001)

encoded_images = []
for i in range(epochs):
    for j, (images, _) in enumerate(data_loader):
    #     images = images.view(images.size(0), -1) 
        images = Variable(images).type(FloatTensor)
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        reconstructions = autoencoder(images)
        loss = torch.dist(images, reconstructions)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        encoded_images.append(encoder(images))
```

But when I add a new vector :

```
features = torch.tensor(np.array([ [1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3] ]))
```

I receive error :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-223-3ca45519e975> in <module>
     32 encoded_images = []
     33 for i in range(epochs):
---> 34     for j, (images, _) in enumerate(data_loader):
     35     #     images = images.view(images.size(0), -1)
     36         images = Variable(images).type(FloatTensor)

ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

Have I setup my data loader correctly ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your Dataset (inside DataLoader) returns only `image` per item *without* label. When you iterate and expecting each item to be `(image, _)` you are trying to unpack a feature without a label into `image` and `_` and this is not possible. This is why you get "not enough values to unpack" error

Comment: ok, in the context of an autoencoder setting a label is redundant but I will try to set dummy label values in order to satisfy the network configuration, thanks

Comment: @blue-sky you don't need to have labels. You simply need your loop variables not to expect any

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what `_` exactly refers to. 
But it is often helpful to take a look at a small example, to see what the code actually does:

Here is your dataloader with batch size `2` and `2` training examples in the dataset:

```py
features = torch.tensor(np.array([ [1,2,3],[1,2,3] ]))

#print(features)

data_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(features, batch_size=2, shuffle=True)
for j, (images) in enumerate(data_loader):
    print(j, images)
```

Output:

```py
0 tensor([[ 1,  2,  3],
        [ 1,  2,  3]])
```

So in your case you unpacked it resp. split your tensor to `(images, _)`:

```py
t = torch.tensor([ [1,2,3],[1,2,3] ])
(images, _) = t
print('images:',images, '_:',_)
# prints: 
# images: tensor([ 1,  2,  3]) _: tensor([ 1,  2,  3])
```

This worked fine for a dataset of two examples and batch size 2, because you could unpack the tensor. However when you have `3` training examples in your dataset the last batch only contains *one* example:

```py
features = torch.tensor(np.array([ [1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]))

#print(features)

data_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(features, batch_size=2, shuffle=True)
for j, (images) in enumerate(data_loader):
    print(j, images)
```

Output:

```py
0 tensor([[ 1,  2,  3],
        [ 1,  2,  3]])
1 tensor([[ 1,  2,  3]])
```

At this point you get the unpacking error, because you cannot split last batch. But as Shai suggested, you are not using any labels, so probably you want to use a completely different setup.

But I hope this example is a bit helpful!